# Using .htaccess on rewritten URLS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm woking with a .htacces file for some caching of individual page. I have a master .htaccess which sits in my doc root, this htaccess redirects everything to a PHP router. The router then provides the content at a given url.

However, for the page I'm working with URL is dynamic and depends on a username.

The url might look like this:

```
http://example.com/username/custom-page
```

The content served to that url lives in:

```
http://example.com/content/custom-page/
```

However, I'm noticing that when I place a .htaccess file in the directory where the files are served it has no effect.

Furthermore, because the url is dynamic, it's difficult to use an individual .htaccess for that page.

Anyway, I'm trying to write to that .htaccess like this:

```
$parent = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/content/custom-page/.htaccess'; 

  if (!is_file($parent)){
    $noCache = '<FilesMatch "\.(.*)$">
      FileETag None
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
      </IfModule>
      </FilesMatch>';

    $file = fopen($parent, "w");
    if (!$file) die("error writing to parent directory");

    fwrite($file, $noCache);
    fclose($file);
    }
else {
    echo "no htaccess";
}
```

I'm getting ""no htaccess" on this. I'm wondering how else I should handle it. I don't really want to set a max age header on the master .htaccess.

Comment: Because you have not even heard about **Front Controller** it makes you think that you have to write it that way. A problem of URL-rewriting has been solved long long time ago. Look at Symfony2, Zend, Laravel - there's basically only one `.htaccess` that contains only one rule for a project!

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple logic error.

```
  if (!is_file($parent)){
```

Note that you are executing your code if the file *does not exist*, and echoing "no htaccess" if the file exists!

I'm not sure why you want this check at all, since you're just overwriting the file if it exists anyway.

And of course, writing the .htaccess in this way is probably not going to have the effect you want, but that is a completely different question.